# Extract MySql ENUM value based on value of tinyint column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a tinyint and enum column.

The enum column(thing_status_texts) holds text representations of the values in the tinyint(thing_status).

I would like to do something like the following psuedo code:

```
SELECT
   thing_id,
   thing_status,
   thing_status_texts[thing_status] AS thing_status_text
```

So, if thing_status_texts has Empty, Full, Removed, and thing_status = 1, then thing_status_text would be 'Full'

Comment: That's not generally how `ENUM` fields are used. Your `ENUM` value should already be `Full` and you just select it.

Comment: Okie, I think you are right. I just learned about ENUM and after reading some more, I realize it is not really what I was thinking.

Comment: Are you sure it's not what you were thinking?  An `ENUM` does all of the magic for you but with only one column.  If you have an enum ('Empty','Full','Removed') you can insert/updated it as 'Full' *or* as '2' and when you select from it you get back the value 'Full' -- or if you select enum_column + 0 you'd get back '2' again.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I need the ENUM to serve as a non-programic way to get a string value for thing_status. I thought it was looked at as individual units that could be read. However, as you said, a value like 2 has to be put in the column. And, as far as I can tell, if I want to get the raw value of thing_status, I would need 2 columns; one tinyint and one enum. This would also mean I have to update both columns when the data is updated. Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you want to use a separate table to store your statuses. Something like this:

```
 status_table                 
+-----------------------------+
|id           |status         |
+-------------+---------------+
|1            |Empty          |
+-------------+---------------+
|2            |Full           |
+-------------+---------------+
|3            |Removed        |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Then in your other table `thing_status` should correspond to the `id` column in your new table. When you select it you use `JOIN`

```
SELECT status FROM your_main_table JOIN status_table ON thing_status=id
```